# Is there a branch of math which studies conventional knots?

Tags: knot-theory

I’ve heard of knot theory, but knot theory differs from what I seek in that its knots are all a single strand and the focus is on topology. I’m wondering if there is a field which studies the actual knots you can make with a cord of some kind, and their properties. If this field exists, what is it called?

Comment: a subbranch of low dimensional topology

Comment: Certain parts of geometry that also cover paper folding, if you want to think about chords with thickness - if you are considering physical objects with physical limits.

Comment: It really depend on what kind of questions you want to answer about knots.

Comment: I studied theoretical knots in algebraic topology  (i.e., the 'ropes' have no width and can be blended with any curvature, that is, they are the image of a continuous, injective map from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R^3$). I don't know what you mean with 'actual' knots. Do you want to take into account things like the length and width of the rope, the material, etc? This would belong to physics or engineering.

Comment: @ajotatxe Perhaps this was a bit more suited for engineering. However, it really seems to me like the overarching patterns that a given micro-scale pattern of intertwined thread can create should be the domain of some field of math.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What would those parts of geometry be referred to as? Is there a specific name?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was also, at one point, looking for anything on the mathematics of origami and I couldn’t find anything. If this field is concerned with Origami, I’d like to hear about it.

Comment: You are looking for the term "knotoid."  This is a relatively recent area of work.  Try Arxiv for a selection: https://arxiv.org/search/?query=knotoid&searchtype=all&source=header

Comment: I think physical knots have been too difficult to study, so there is a lot more about ideal knots (and Turaev's knotoids, as N. Owad mentions). There have been some things in calculating something called the *rope length* of a knot. I also remember some calculations somewhere to find stresses in thick knotted cords under tension, but I'm not sure of a reference -- it might have been knotted developable surfaces? or I could been misremembering a Mobius band developable surface.

Comment: @KyleMiller thank you